# How to implement list view inside fragment android studio Kotlin

Tags: android, listview, kotlin, fragment, implements

How to implement list view inside fragment android studio Kotlin
I am new to programming and I want to make my app a simple listview of names of places by region.

This is the fragment name VisayasMindanao

```
package com.gumangan.uecficenterslist
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.ListView


class VisayasMindanao : Fragment(){

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

val centerlist = resources.getStringArray(R.array.region2)

//Creating Array of Region 
var lv = findViewById(R.id.content_main_lview) as ListView 
val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, centerlist)
lv.adapter = adapter

    return LayoutInflater.from(container?.context).inflate(R.layout.visayas_mindanao, container, false)
}
```

}

This is in my layout name visayas_mindanao

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/visayas_mindanao_lview"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And I'm trying to get values from here

```
<resources>
<string name="region1">
    <item>ARANAAR TI BAGGAK TI DAYA
    acarra, Ilocos Norte
    </item>
</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: in `onCreateView`, put your code to above `return`

Comment: Im sorry I dont understand, what code shall I add

Comment: Please mention the issue you have

Comment: I am creating an app that when i click one of options in navigation drawer a fragment will open and a listview would show, I trying to implement listview in fragment with this simple basic code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are two issue in your codes:

**First:**

Override should have ending point "}" and remove the other after the last "}".

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    return LayoutInflater.from(container?.context).inflate(R.layout.visayas_mindanao, container, false)

}
```

**Second:**

Another issue is your declaration of `StringArrays` which it should be like this:

```
<string-array name="sample_region1">
        <item>
    Your first item
        </item>
         <item>
    Your Second item
        </item>
    ...
    ..
    .
</string-array>
```

And of course, setting the list:

```
val centerlist = resources.getStringArray(R.array.sample_region1)
```

---

**Edit:** Your ListView id is `visayas_mindanao_lview` but in java it is: `content_main_lview` just set in java:

```
class VisayasMindanao : Fragment() {

   override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.visayas_mindanao, container, false)

        val centerlist = resources.getStringArray(R.array.region2)
        var lv = view.findViewById<ListView>(R.id.visayas_mindanao_lview)

        val adapter = ArrayAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, centerlist)
        lv.adapter = adapter

        return view
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks no error but the the app crash when its opening

Comment: Which error? could you show me or update your post? Thank you

Comment: I updated my post above,  still having error findViewById is red

Comment: Check my updated answer. problem is your id of `ListView`

Comment: no thats not the error, its findViewById and Array adapter is underlinedin red

Comment: I have rechecked and edited my answer. it should work now

Comment: @RaffyGumangan Happy to hear that. I still don’t get the point of downvoting. Interesting!

Comment: Sorry for that Moshen but I didnt downvote, maybe other users, I cannot upvote or downvote because I am below 15 reputation. I am still new to to stack overflow. But I already check mark this answer because it solve my problem.

Comment: @RaffyGumangan Oh i know. Welcome to StackoverFlow BTW and happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

Since you said you are new. in many languages that i know, codes after return statements are never run.

Do something like this

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    return LayoutInflater.from(container?.context).inflate(R.layout.visayas_mindanao, container, false)
}

override fun onViewCreated(){
 val lv = findViewById(R.id.visayas_mindanao_lview) as ListView
    val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listOf("car", "plane"))
    lv.adapter = adapter
}
```

If you reading from resources, do this

```
override fun onViewCreated(){
     val lv = findViewById(R.id.visayas_mindanao_lview) as ListView
        val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, resources.getStringArray(// the resource ID of the array))
        lv.adapter = adapter
    }
```

Make sure your resources looks like what @nitinkumarp said.

If this worked for you, check it as the answer. to help other beginners. thanks

Comment: but i am getting strings from resources, because i have more than 50 to input.

Comment: Thanks you for helping but still getting error with findViewById, I already run it by the code given by Moshen

Answer (score 1):

I tested and it worked very well. Here is my code:

**MainActivity (who has the frameLayout)**

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        setFragment(FirstFragment())
    }

    fun setFragment(f: Fragment) {

        val ft = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()

        ft.replace(R.id.framelayout, f)
        ft.commit()
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/framelayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**fragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".FirstFragment">


    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/visayas_mindanao_lview"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**fragment.kt**

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.ListView

/**
 * A simple [Fragment] subclass.
 */
class FirstFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val context = context as MainActivity
        val centerlist = resources.getStringArray(R.array.region1)

        val lv = context.findViewById(R.id.visayas_mindanao_lview) as ListView
        val adapter = ArrayAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, centerlist)
        lv.adapter = adapter
    }
}
```

**values: strings.xml**

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="region1">
        <item>item1</item>
        <item>item2</item>
        <item>item3</item>
        <item>item4</item>
        <item>item5</item>
        <item>item6</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your String Array resources is not in correct format.
Add it like in following format:

```
<string-array name="sample_region1">
    <item>ACAYA
Nalasin, Solsona, Ilocos Norte</item>
    <item>ALPHA KEN OMEGA
Imelda Marcos, Ilocos Norte</item>

</string-array>
```

Answer (score -1):

As the documentation says:

> Note: For better performance in your list, you should instead build
>   your list with RecyclerView.

Also, you can find a full example for both implementations in the official documentation. See: 
[ListView documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview),
[RecyclerView documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview)

Edit: +1 for moving your code *above* the return statement otherwise it won't be executed.